# How to use first of type

Tags: jquery, html, css

my html code
i wont get only first `a[rel=next]` element

```
<div id="devices">
    <div class="display-controls">
        <div class="pagenav">
            <a rel="next" class="ahrf" href=".html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a rel="last" class="ahrf" href=".html">Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    /**some code**/

    <div class="display-controls">
        <div class="pagenav">
            <a rel="next" class="ahrf" href=".html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a rel="last" class="ahrf" href=".html">Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to get only first `<a rel="next"`
my try

```
 $('.display-controls .pagenav a[rel="next"]:first-of-type')
```

not working

Comment: no need for the \ and there is no `forum-display-controls` in your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif it did not change the result

Comment: where is `.forum-display-controls` ? that's what @TemaniAfif was saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as below:

```js
var res = $('.display-controls .pagenav a[rel="next"]:first');
console.log("result",res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="devices">
    <div class="display-controls">
        <div class="pagenav">
            <a rel="next" class="ahrf" href=".html">next1<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a rel="last" class="ahrf" href=".html">Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    /**some code**/

    <div class="display-controls">
        <div class="pagenav">
            <a rel="next" class="ahrf" href=".html">next2<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a rel="last" class="ahrf" href=".html">Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:first-of-type` selector in CSS allows you to target the first occurrence of an element **within its container**.

Problem with your selector is all the elements matching `a[rel="next"]` are actually `first of type` child of their parent, so all of them will be selected.

You want to select the first anchor of your first `.display-controls` div, you need to mention that in your selector. You should use this selector

`'.forum-display-controls .display-controls:first-of-type a[rel="next"]'`

Answer (score 0):

The following selector can be used to select the first item with the requirements:

```
$('.forum-display-controls .pagenav a[rel="next"]:first-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method:

```js
$('.pagenav a[rel="next"]').first();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="devices">
    <div class="display-controls">
        <div class="pagenav">
            <a rel="next" class="ahrf" href=".html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a rel="last" class="ahrf" href=".html">Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    /**some code**/

    <div class="display-controls">
        <div class="pagenav">
            <a rel="next" class="ahrf" href=".html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a rel="last" class="ahrf" href=".html">Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `<a rel="next"` use `document.querySelector('.ahrf')`

Comment: Or you can use `document.querySelector("a[rel=import]").import.querySelector("next")`

Answer (score -1):

try this one...

```
$('.pagenav a:first-child')
```